# Netbeans - XDebug Debugging

Tags: php, netbeans, xdebug

I have setup a new dev environment using windows for the first time. I have WAMP installed and I am using netbeans as my IDE and have XDebug installed and reference in my php.ini file.

```
; XDEBUG Extension

zend_extension = "c:/wamp/bin/php/php5.4.12/zend_ext/php_xdebug-2.2.3-5.4-vc9-x86_64.dll"
```

which points to my xdebug.dll file.

When I try to debug within netbeans however, it is not stopping on any of my breakpoints. Any ideas of how to get it correctly debug by stopping at my breakpoints? Also just to verify that i am going to the page in question with my firefox browser so its not that I am not running the code

[image]

[image: Netbeans Debug Config]

Answer (score 1):

I added the following to my php.ini file and now debugging is stopping on my breakpoints in netbeans

```
xdebug.remote_autostart=on
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_handler="dbgp"
xdebug.remote_host="localhost"
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.idekey="netbeans-xdebug"
```